# Passing messages from a controller to a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a function on my application that provides "data validation" functionality. The user goes to a page and uploads a file, where my controller takes the data, parses it, and then returns a list of messages for the user.

For example, the user uploads a txt file containing a number of arbitrary "fruit" and the application determines whether they are fruit or not

```
apple
banana
orange
grapes
carrot
```

The controller will examine each line and then send the user to a new page that will say something like

```
apple - Yes
banana - Yes
orange - Yes
grapes - Yes
carrot - No
```

I am thinking of trying out both JSON as well as an array of messages. Either way, how do I pass values from the controller to the view? I will be using `redirect_to` at some point to redirect them to the post-upload page where they can check the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data from a controller to a view by storing the information in a controller instance variable, since Rails makes those variables available to the view as well, per http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html.

Comment: Initially I was using `redirect_to`, but then I realized that the instance variable I was setting was being cleared out since the method that runs before loading the view initializes the variable. I switched to `render action` and it seems to work the way I want it to.